# finding employees that are always together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a homework assignment on a company database with relations as follows:

```
Employee(eid,ename,salary,did,classification)  - primary key is eid
Project(pid,pname,did,budget,duedate)  - primary key is pid
Onproject(pid,eid,fdate) - primary key is (pid,eid)
```

There are more relations, but I don't think they are relevant `(department,budget)`.

I need to find and display workers id(eid) that are always doing the same projects(always together). I need to display every pair only once.

I'm trying this:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT (e1.eid , e2.eid)

FROM
employee as e1 , employee as e2 

WHERE

e1.eid<>e2.eid  
AND e1.eid in 
(SELECT eid,pid as A from onproject where pid IN(
 (select pid as B from onproject where eid = e2.eid )INTERSECT (select pid as AB from onproject where eid = e1.eid)))
AND 
e2.eid in 
(SELECT eid,pid as C from onproject where pid IN
 ((select pid as D from onproject where eid = e1.eid) intersect (select pid as AC from onproject where eid = e2.eid)))
```

Comment: What does "always together" mean exactly? What if two employees are always working the same projects except one project where only one of the employees works on, is that "always together" as well?

Comment: Unrelated, to your problem, but: `DISTINCT` is **NOT**  a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Putting parentheses around the columns won't change anything for that. `select distinct (a),b` is the same as `select distinct a,(b)` or `select distinct a,b` - additionally: `distinct (a,b)` is actually an error in any DBMS other than Postgres

Comment: i thought so about the distinct ..
always together rules out the possibility of having even one project that only one of them is working on

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt test because of lack of data  but
Try this:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT (e1.eid , e2.eid)
FROM
employee as e1 cross join employee as e2 
where e1.eid<>e2.eid 
and not exists(select 1 from Onproject o1 where e1.eid in (select edi from Onproject o2 and o2.pid = o1.pid) and e2.eid not in (select eid from Onproject o2 and o2.pid = o1.pid)
)
and not exists(select 1 from Onproject o1 where e1.eid not in (select eid from Onproject o2 and o2.pid = o1.pid) and e2.eid in (select edi from Onproject o2 and o2.pid = o1.pid)
)
```

Comment: Close, just a few `AND` that should `WHERE` :) And because of `e1.eid<>e2.eid` you get them double.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know the eid pairs?

Then a self-join of the "onproject" table, comparing pair totals to the individual totals, could suffice.

```
WITH EMP_TOT AS
(
    SELECT eid
    , COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS Total
    FROM onproject
    GROUP BY eid
)
SELECT eid1, eid2
, pairs.Total AS PairTotal
, emp1.Total AS Emp1Total
, emp2.Total AS Emp2Total
FROM
(
    SELECT p1.eid AS eid1, p2.eid AS eid2
    , COUNT(DISTINCT p1.pid) AS Total
    FROM onproject p1
    JOIN onproject p2 
      ON p1.pid = p2.pid
     AND p1.eid < p2.eid
    GROUP BY p1.eid, p2.eid
) pairs
LEFT JOIN EMP_TOT emp1 ON emp1.eid = pairs.eid1
LEFT JOIN EMP_TOT emp2 ON emp2.eid = pairs.eid2
WHERE emp1.Total = pairs.Total
  AND emp2.Total = pairs.Total
ORDER BY pairs.Total DESC
```

**For example, when using this sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE onproject (
   eid INT,
   pid INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (eid, pid)
);
INSERT INTO onproject (eid, pid) VALUES
(101, 10), (102, 10), (103, 10), (104, 10),
(102, 11), (999, 11), (103, 11),
(101, 12), (102, 12), (103, 12), (104, 12);
```

**The results are:**

```
eid1    eid2    pairtotal   emp1total   emp2total
102     103     3           3           3
101     104     2           2           2
```

But you're free to left join the employee table to get the names.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . a self join and aggregation come to mind:

```
select op1.eid, op2.eid
from onproject op1 join
     onproject op2
     on op1.pid = op2.pid and op1.eid < op2.eid
group by op1, op2
having count(*) = (select count(*) from onproject op where op.eid = op1.eid) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from onproject op where op.eid = op2.eid);
```

If there are duplicates in `onproject` for given employee on a given project, then the query needs to be modified a bit with `count(distinct)`s.